# How to integrate pydantic with pymongo?

Tags: python, json, pymongo, pydantic

I get a simple Json from my mongodb with pymongo which I want to validate using pydantic:

```
from pydantic import TypeAdapter, BaseModel, Json

# contents is the mongodb collection and returns this
# content = [{"content": {}}]
content = list(contents.find(projection={'_id': 0}))

class Content(BaseModel):
    content: Json

print(TypeAdapter(list[Content]).validate_python(content))
```

This raises this error:

```
0.content
  JSON input should be string, bytes or bytearray [type=json_type, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/json_type
(dissident-ui-backend-py3.11) [tom@freshbook dissident-ui-backend]$
```

I understood that pydantic wants the content value to be an escaped JSON string, but pymongo returns a dict. How can I solve this without iterating overall content and manually json.dumps() all content???